# How to find the minimal amount of ordered pairs for specific counts of elements?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have around $350$ sets of ordered pairs (representing firms). All firms have properties, which I can represent numerically as $(x;y)$, where
$x$ is a natural number $\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and
$y$ is $\in \{6,7,8,9,10\}.$

An example of this would be:
Firm A= $(1;8)$
Firm B= $(4;6)$
Firm C= $(2;10)$
Firm D= $(5;10)$
I need to come up with a way to maximize the use of these pairs in order to achieve a specific sum of different elements.

Count of elements:
$35$ of element 10;
$24$ of element 9;
$27$ of element 8;
$53$ of element 7;
$34$ of element 6;
$36$ of element 5;
$25$ of element 4;
$25$ of element 3;
$31$ of element 2; and
$6$ of element 1.

I know that I cannot find a way to use these ordered pairs in order to fully meet my needs. But how can I use these pairs to meet my needs to the greatest extent possible?